# Perl program to Remove segment in a file

Tags: shell, perl

I have a file which contains the following

```
blah
blah blah
Zebra
Blah blah blah
Blah
Bleh
Dog
Blag 
Noblah
Someblah
```

I want to remove the line segment from Zebra and Dog. Remove only those where Zebra occurs first and Dog occurs later.

How to do this in a perl script ?

Answer (score 4):

Like [How do I remove a specific area of element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525450/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-area-of-element-from-an-array/15529167#15529167), this is a use case for the flip-flop operator.

```
perl -ne 'print unless /Zebra/ .. /Dog/' < input-file
```

Answer (score 3):

```bash
perl -ne'$r ||= /^Zebra$/; print if !$r; $r &&= !/^Dog$/;'
```

or

```bash
perl -ne'print if !( /^Zebra$/ .. /^Dog$/ );'
```

These assume every Zebra and Dogs are paired, and that they can't be nested.

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).